# Actualizar cliente Git en windows

Tags: git, windows10

De repente mi cliente de git dejó de funcionar y me manda este error:

```
C:\Users\Administrador.000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\datastructurestypescript>git pull
```

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/javatlacati/datastructurestypescript.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

La versión que tengo instalada es **1.9.5-preview2015019**.

Quisiera saber a que se debe ese error y si existe alguna forma de solucionarlo de peferencia sin reinstalar que es lo primeo que voy a intentar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es como podán ver que la versión me indica que fue descargado en el año 2015 y al momento de instalarlo no le indiqué que quería que verificara si habia nuevas actualizaciones diariamente.

Desde consola existe un comando para actualziar sin reinstalar que es el siguiente en el caso de windows:

```
git update-git-for-windows
```